# Make this slider autoplay with pure css

Tags: html, css

```css
.slider-container {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: skyblue;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-color: skyblue;
}
.menu {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 900;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
}
.menu label {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 50px;
 margin: 0 .2em 1em;
 &:hover {
  background: red;
 }
}
.slide {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 500px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 padding: 8em 1em 0;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 transition: left 0s .75s;
}
[id^="slide"]:checked+.slide {
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 transition: left .65s ease-out;
}
.slide-1 {
 background-image: url("http://all4desktop.com/data_images/original/4238179-pictures.jpg");
}
.slide-2 {
 background-image: url("http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/180/4210843-picture.jpg");
}
.slide-3 {
 background-image: url("http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/179/5793047-picture.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="slider-container">
  <div class="menu">
   <label for="slide-dot-1"></label> <label for="slide-dot-2"></label> <label for="slide-dot-3"></label>
  </div><input checked id="slide-dot-1" name="slides" type="radio">
  <div class="slide slide-1"></div><input id="slide-dot-2" name="slides" type="radio">
  <div class="slide slide-2"></div><input id="slide-dot-3" name="slides" type="radio">
  <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
 </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I got this code and i really like it. I wanted to learn how to make it go autoplay since it is manually operated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS carousel you can look at, it slides on its own and stops sliding if the user clicks the arrows for manual control.

```js
//Changed index so 1 is actually first image, rather than starting at 0 index
var index = 1;
var paused = false;
var slideShow = [];

for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow").length; i++) {
  slideShow[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[i];
  slideShow[i].style.display = "none";
}

slideShow[0].style.display = "inline";

var slides = setInterval(function() {
  if (index < slideShow.length) {
    index++;
    showDivs();
  }
  else {
    index = 1;
    showDivs();
  }
},1000);

function control(n) {
  clearInterval(slides);

  if (index+n > slideShow.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  else if (index+n <= 0) {
    index = slideShow.length;
  }
  else {
    index += n;
  }
  showDivs();
}

function showDivs() {
  //Hide all slideShow elements, and then show only the targeted element
  for (let i=1; i<=slideShow.length; i++) {
    slideShow[i-1].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideShow[index-1].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="control(-1)" class="arrows" id="left"><</button>
<p class="slideShow">1</p>
<p class="slideShow">2</p>
<p class="slideShow">3</p>
<p class="slideShow">4</p>
<p class="slideShow">5</p>
<button onclick="control(1)" class="arrows" id="right">></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey use transition duration infinite to make it autoplay